# Checked List Box requires me to select an Item twice

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a checked list box that is acting strangely - for every item I want to select, I have to click on it twice.

Click once:

[image: Click on the item]

Click Twice:

[image: Click on the item again]

Is there a workaround to solve this?

Comment: What happens when you click on the actual CheckBox instead of the text?

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky it's the same. I need to click on the item twice in a row to check the item, doesn't matter where I click on it.

Comment: @TheIndianProgrammmer there is no code for this - I have not created this dynamically, unless you are suggesting I give you the Designer code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are looking for the CheckOnClick Property[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is there a CheckOnClick property you set to true?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is Windows Forms.  There should be a property on the CheckedListBox called Check on Click.  Set that to True for the behavior you're looking for.